# WebForm CustomValidator postsback after client validation fails

Tags: webforms, client-side-validation, customvalidator

I have a customValidator with validation on both the client and server.

Here is the markup:

```
<input id="theDate" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valValidateDate" runat="server" 
    ClientValidationFunction="checkDate" 
    ControlToValidate="theDate" 
    ValidateEmptyText="True" >Error Message Text</asp:CustomValidator>
```

My client side validation function is simple.  It just sets it the field to not valid.

```
function checkDate(src, args) {
    args.IsValid = false;
    //alert(args.IsValid);
    return false;
}
```

I think this should stop the postBack but it does not.

If I uncomment that alert I see that the value is false - and that stops the postBack.  In fact, having the alert alone stops the postback.

With the alert, which stops the postBack, I see the error message as long as I set args.IsValid to false - even without a return = false.

How do I stop the postback when the clientside validation fails?

I'm using:
firefox and chrome
Visual Studio 2010
Asp.Net webForms - framework 4.0.3

Comment: Please see [Existing SO Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016843/asp-customvalidator-advancing-to-postback-after-error

Comment: I have seen that question.  It does not seem to solve the problem.  The answer there is to have a source and argument parameter which I have.  Then set argument.isValid to false which I show in my example.  Can you be more specific about how that question address my issue?